# How to stop Javascript counter after initial result is returned

Tags: javascript

I need to stop a counter after returning its initial result so that the result can then be innerHTL inserted as a static number off which subsequent, separate scripts rely.

The counter works great for continual counting, but I can't stop the darned thing for the life of me.

I've tried clearInterval, stopPropagation, modifying variables, but I'm honestly just too much of a disaster to know where to make those (or other) changes to stop and hold the initial returned value.

```
var counterData = {'startCounter':'1','startingDate':'02\/01\/2019','incrementPerSecond':'2','counterInterval':'3'};

var canYouBelieveThisGuy = function () {
    'use strict';

    if ($("#stat_counter").length > 0) {

        var currentstat =  parseFloat(counterData['startCounter'].replace(/[^\d.-]/g,''));
        var intervalSeconds = counterData['counterInterval'] * 1000; //1000;
        var increaseUnit = counterData['incrementPerSecond'];
        var initialDate = new Date(counterData["startingDate"]);

    setInterval(function () {

        var currentDate = new Date();
        var timeDiffSeconds = (currentDate - initialDate)/1000;
        var increment = timeDiffSeconds * increaseUnit;
        var currentstat2 = parseInt(currentstat + increment) * 100;
        currentstat2 = (currentstat2 / 100).toFixed(0)
        var num = (currentstat2);
        $("#stat_counter").text(num);
        }, intervalSeconds);
    };
    }
    (jQuery, this);
```

The returned value should be the number produced after the initial run, and should stop running entirely thereafter.

Thanks for the help and for being gentle!

Comment: clearInterval with the right timerID should do the job. Can you show us how did you use clearInterval ?

Comment: when you say you tried clearInterval, what exactly did you do because that is correct but in your code you don't set a var for the setInterval.

Comment: Is the interval function only being executed once? Why not use setTimeout? This makes it run once after a specified amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the blazing fast replies, everyone! I'm glad to hear I was on the right track, but honestly, I have no idea where to insert the clearInterval or setTimeout methods. Any pointers are definitely welcome. Thanks, again!

Comment: As imvain2 said, you should assign the setInterval result to a variable, e.g. `var variableName = setInterval(function{});`. You should then call clearInterval and pass the variable as an argument to clear it: `clearInterval(variableName)`. I'd still strongly recommend looking into setTimeout, but that's just an opinion.

Comment: After reading your question carefully, it seems like you're just trying to calculate how much a counter would count if it was started at `startDate` and increments by `incrementsPerSecond` each second since then. Is that correct? Then why would you even need a timer or interval if you just going to stop it after it's first tick?

Comment: You've all been excellent with your willingness to help out! After the astute observation by @Mikepote, it does seem that I need to switch gears to a simpler approach, as I do only need the initial value that I can then reference in later functions. Now off to stumbling my way through that discovery, I guess. (Imagine your grandpa trying to code without his glasses and with the cat repeatedly walking over the keyboard. That's this guy!) Thanks, again, everyone!